# How to show page loading spinner in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show page loading spinner using below code in jquery mobile 1.3 Android native app, but it is not working, can any one help me what the issue is and how to make it work

```
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="createPage" data-role="page">
   <script>
    $("#createPage").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
    $mobile.loading('show');
    processCreateBtnAction(); //This takes 5 seconds to complete the operation
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
</script>
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
```

Comment: NOTE: you have $mobile, rather than $.mobile. Hopefully that is not your error?

Comment: oh i think "." got missed in my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are good. I personally use a slightly different varition of the same basic technique - create a large enough break in the Javascript processing, that the UI will have enough time to redraw itself.

```
$("#createPage").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    setTimeout(function(){
        processCreateBtnAction(); //This takes 5 seconds to complete the operation
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, 20);
});
```

This will create a 20 millisecond timeout after 'show' is called. Which is enough time for the UI to redraw itself before the CPU heavy processCreateBtnAction() function is called.

I've experimented with different timings, and have found that 20 milliseconds is the best timeout to use. Some people try to use 0 or something like that - which will work on faster devices. But on an iPad 1 or something like that which is quite slow, you need to have a decent timeout, or you won't get enough time for the screen to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is slightly different to other programming languages as it will not wait for the actions within the function `processCreateBtnAction()` to complete before moving onto the next line - which is why your spinner is being hidden.

One way around this is to use callback functions (as in Javascript, functions can be passed around as objects). Something along the lines of:

```
$("#createPage").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
    $mobile.loading('show');
    processCreateBtnAction($.mobile.loading('hide'));
});

function processCreateBtnAction(callback) {
    // Rest of your function here

    callback(); // $.mobile.loading('hide') will be called here.
}
```

Comment: Unless `processCreateBtnAction()` is doing something asynchronously (as the name implies), JS should be waiting for the function to complete before it hides the throbber. So it has nothing to do with javascript as a language more so than it does with what he's doing in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of  `$mobile.loading('show');`:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1);
```